# How can I re adjust my images to be proportional and fit on orientation change?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ios7, imageview

When an image appears in my modal view, I want the image to scale correctly, like so:

If the view is landscape:

- If it is a landscape image it should fit to the screen bounds
- If it is a portrait image it should center

If the view is portrait

- If it is a portrait image fit vertical center
- Same for landscape image

I have the portrait view ok because I use scale to aspect fit, which works great in portrait

However, no matter what I do I cannot seem to get the images to scale/resize/position correctly when I change to landscape.

Thank you in advance.

```
 (void)viewDidLoad
  {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.scollView.delegate=self;

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

[self.viewImage addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

}

```
- (void)resetContentMode:(UIImageView *)imageView
   {
   if (imageView.image == nil)
    return;

CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size;
CGSize imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size;

if (imageSize.height == 0 || imageViewSize.height == 0)
    return;

CGFloat imageRatio        = imageSize.width     / imageSize.height;
CGFloat imageViewRatio    = imageViewSize.width / imageViewSize.height;
CGFloat percentDifference = fabs(imageRatio - imageViewRatio) / imageViewRatio;

if (percentDifference < 0.25)
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
else
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}






      -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer   shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer    *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

{
         return YES;
   }

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return YES;
  }

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
  } 
          -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:     (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
  {
       if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        [self resetContentMode:im];
    }
      else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||      toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {




        [self resetContentMode:im];
     }
  }


   - (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
[self.scollView setZoomScale:self.scollView.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{

    [self resetContentMode:im];
}
   else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{

     [self resetContentMode:im];

      }


   }
    - (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
   [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]    statusBarOrientation]];}
```

Comment: Actually this is day one of using objective c it's an extension to a phonegap app (my last one I'm learning native ) so I don't know how to use auto layout  and what it does.  As for pinch zoom no. And I already have double tap to zoom implemented and it works already

Comment: @Rob, is it easier to use auto layout if so how can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need pinch-zoom, but rather just need to tweak the appearance of the image view based upon whether the orientation of the image matches that of the image view, you can retire the scrollview in this process.

You can accomplish the desired effect with just an image view, but changing the `contentMode` based upon how close the ratio of the image dimensions are to the image view's ratio of dimensions. If they're close, I'll default to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` (and because the ratios are close to each other, I don't have to worry about too much getting clipped). If they're not close, I'll default to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` (because the ratios are not close, I know a lot would get clipped if I used "fill", so instead I default to "fit").

```
- (void)resetContentMode:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    if (imageView.image == nil)
        return;

    CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size;
    CGSize imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size;

    if (imageSize.height == 0 || imageViewSize.height == 0)
        return;

    CGFloat imageRatio        = imageSize.width     / imageSize.height;
    CGFloat imageViewRatio    = imageViewSize.width / imageViewSize.height;
    CGFloat percentDifference = fabs(imageRatio - imageViewRatio) / imageViewRatio;

    if (percentDifference < 0.25)
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    else
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

I then, whenever I rotate, call this method again. For example:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self resetContentMode:self.imageView];
}
```

I also turn on `userInteractionEnabled` on the image, and have a double tap gesture that toggles between the two content modes:

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (id)gesture.view;

    if (imageView.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit)
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    else if (imageView.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill)
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    else
        [self resetContentMode:imageView];
}
```

I'll also make sure that the `UIImageView` has its `clipsToBounds` set to YES, such that when it's using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, I don't have to worry about the image bleeding over the `bounds` of the image view.

This is a quick-and-dirty solution, but it works pretty well for simple scenarios, where you only want to worry about aspect fit vs aspect fill.

Comment: will this work if i put my image view in a scroll view and perform the double tap to zoom operations?

Comment: @Dnaso If the sole purpose of the scroll view was to enable double-tap, this eliminates the need for the scroll view altogether (and in fact this is incompatible with the scroll view's double tap). If you need/want to use the scroll view, the above will not work. It's just a quick-n-dirty algorithm I use for determining which content mode is to be used when putting image in image view. If you need scroll view, let me know.

Comment: i dont neccessarily need the scroll view. However, when i was just double tapping and using affline transforms its quirky. at least with a scroll view everything got set back to place so to speak. I am a web developer so objC structure is quite different. ..just to make sure I am getting this straight: when i orientation change i have to reload the views correct and it redraws all my views?

Comment: what I really want to accomplish is the following...  have my image view fit to screen or at least be centered on orientation change depending on image orientation. two: I want to double tap zoom double tap back out to normal which works.. the only thing that does not work is the views reloading and centering the content which is embarrassing because this seems very elementary

Comment: should I then take my image view out of the scroll view or should i leave it there and adjust my doubetap selector to point to the imageview?

Comment: this works (the image zooming, however, it does not change the image view size or adjust the image when i rotate.. i updated the code at the bottom of my post

Comment: I completely understand that. the problem is the image view will not resize. IE my imageview background is black. when i rotate to the left only the left side of the phone is black compared to the image view filling the phone width and the image being centered within the phone. the code you gave me does work for changing the aspect type.  what I am trying to do is center the image in the image view and make the image view fill the phone height/width because as of right now that is not working.

Comment: hmm I'm guessing not? I am trying to set it from an example but apparently my views have no visible interface? Should I set the methods in the view did load or the orientation change?

Comment: @Dnaso let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42424/discussion-between-rob-and-dnaso)

Comment: after I figured out auto layouts it worked thank you